# My code doesnt return token address from contract

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, testnets

contract.js file:

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import CustomDexABI from "../utils/CustomDex.json";
import CustomTokenABI from "../utils/CustomToken.json";

export const tokenContract = async (address) => {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
  const { ethereum } = window;

  if (ethereum) {
    const signer = provider.getSigner();

    const contractReader = new ethers.Contract(
      address,
      CustomTokenABI.abi,
      signer
    )

    return contractReader;
  }
};

export const contract = async () => {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
  const { ethereum } = window;

  if (ethereum) {
    const signer = provider.getSigner();

    const contractReader = new ethers.Contract(
      "0xD607D33873D2A895A2F08Da8a16A8aa0c0a6b8E9",
      CustomDexABI.abi,
      signer
    );

    return contractReader;
  }
};


this fuction returns undefined

import { BigNumber, ethers } from "ethers";
import { contract, tokenContract } from "./contract";
import { toEth } from "./utils";

export async function getTokenAddress(tokenName) {
  try {
    const contractObj = await contract();
    const address = await contractObj.getTokenAddress(tokenName);

    return address;
  } catch (e) {
    return parseErrorMsg(e);
  }
}
```

The chain is polygon mumbai

Comment: Does your contract have a `getTokenAddress()` function? Could you please add the contract ABI (i.e., the content of the **CustomDex.json** file) in the question to confirm?